# WCF Error: "The given key was not present in the dictionary." on initializing client proxy

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-binding

I am getting the following error: "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

The code is just trying to create a proxy client connection:

```
FileService.FileServiceClient svc = new CCS.FileService.FileServiceClient();
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelSectionGroup.get_Client()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupChannel(String configurationName, String contractName, Boolean wildcard)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
   at CCS.FileService.FileServiceClient..ctor()
   at CCS.MainPage..ctor()
   at CCS.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

I have a silverlight 3 app that I am adding a WCF Service to on the Web Application.  Anyone know a way to fix this problem?  It looks like it is having a hard time trying to get the binding information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [this is an issue with the Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/jamlew/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-tools-issue-new-wcf-template-is-broken-by-silverlight-2-sdk.aspx) loading the wrong Silverlight 2 file instead of the Silverlight 3 one:

> To work around this issue for now, uninstall the Silverlight 2 SDK, update your service reference, and rebuild your Silverlight application.
>
> If you want your service to be consumable by both Silverlight 2 and Silverlight 3 applications, you can change the binding back to basicHttpBinding.  To do that, edit the web.config file for the web project containing the service.  Then update the service reference and rebuild your Silverlight application.